# LaTeX: how to change indentation of chapter and sections in report document class?

Tags: spacing, sectioning

It seems like relative to the paragraph text, the `chapter` and `section` titles have a default indentation that I'd like to manually set. Is there a way to do this using

```
\setlength{\...}{}
```

? I'd rather not mess with `\titlesec` since I've got multiple files and using `titlesec` previously messed up with my formatting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Can you complete your code snippet to an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Please don't cross-post on [SO] and here, at least not without disclosure. Many *TeX question get migrated here from SO at any rate, as is the case with your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83250

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a predefined length for this in the standard classes but it is easy to copy the definitions from `report.cls` and  add some leftskip:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\section{aaaaa}

aaaa

\makeatletter


\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\leftskip1in \normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

\makeatother

\section{aaaaa}

aaaa

\end{document}
```

---

Note as shown in the section 0.1 example the default indentation is zero.